# Getting #value with formula for splitting delimited string

Tags: excel-formula, find

I have cells containing between 0 and 5 names, delimited by semi-colons. For example:

2 names:

Shakespeare, William; Sartre, Jean-Paul

3 names:

Shakespeare, William; Sartre, Jean-Paul; Ishiguro, Kazuo

4 names:

Shakespeare, William; Sartre, Jean-Paul; Ishiguro, Kazuo; Blyton, Enid

I want to put each name into its own cell but for some formulae I get the #VALUE! error.

I'm going blind looking at these formulae.

Where there are 2 names, in new cell 3 I have the following formula:

```
=IF(SUM(LEN(F85))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F85,";","")))>1,TRIM(MID(F85&";", FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)+1,FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)+1)- FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)-1)),"")
This works fine - I get an empty cell.

Where there are 3 names, in new cell 4 I have the following formula:
=IF(SUM(LEN(F85))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F85,",","")))>2,TRIM(MID(F85&";", FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";", FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)+1)+1,FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";", FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)+1)+1)- FIND(";",F85&";",FIND(";",F85&";", FIND(";",F85&";",1)+1)+1)-1)),"")
```

This time, in new cell 4, I get #VALUE!

Where there are 4 names, in new cell 5 I have the following formula:

```
=IF(SUM(LEN(F87))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F87,",","")))>3,TRIM(MID(F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";",FIND(";",F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";",1)+1)+1)+1)+1,FIND(";",F87&";",FIND(";",F87&";",FIND(";",F87&";",FIND(";",F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";",1)+1)+1)+1)+1)- FIND(";",F87&";",FIND(";",F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";", FIND(";",F87&";",1)+1)+1)+1)-1)),"")
```

This time, in new cell 5, I get #VALUE!

I can't figure out why I'm getting the errors.

I expect each new cell to contain surname, first name, but some formulae give the #VALUE! error.

Comment: does the solution helps?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.

[image]